# Scipy.misc.imread() is depriciated

Tags: python, scipy

I'm working on a project and I'm referring this particular [repository](https://github.com/thePetrMarek/SequenceOfDigitsRecognition/blob/master/inference.py) which have used scipy.misc

The line of code which I'm trying to replace:

`scipy.misc.imresize(scipy.misc.imread(image), (128, 256))` where image is the file location

The alternative approaches which I've tried are:

`np.array(Image.fromarray(image).resize((128,256)))`

`cv2.resize(cv2.imread(image,0), (256, 128))`

but nothing worked. Can anyone please help me out in this?

Comment: what means nothing worked? What should happen and what actually happened when you tried the alternative approaches?

Comment: "You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float". 
I'm getting this error though I try by defining a tensorflow placeholder of shape (128,256) but the same error is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Try imageio and scikit-image

```py
import imageio
from skimage import transform

img = imageio.imread(path_to_img)
img = transform.resize(img, (128, 256))
```

Comment: By gray scaling was able to read it `imageio.imread(image,as_gray=True)`, but still have the same issue "You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float", I created a placeholder and defined it inside the feed_dict. But the error still persists. Seems like it is due to model

Comment: Dude you have to provide your Tensorflow code, otherwise we will have no idea what's going on

Comment: I'm referring the above mentioned repository (for digits of variable length)